# how to find a value in all columns and put it into a new column?

Tags: python, excel, loops, vlookup

I'm trying to find a value that start with 'date' in all columns, and put in into a new column according to their index.

Here's the file I have :

[image]

I tried used this function :

```
=@IF(@letf(B:AH,4)="date",B:AH," ")
```

but it return #NAME?. any idea if it can be achieve using excel or using python?

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you post a sample? Also, please, post some data we can copy-paste.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the output to be in the new column?  Would you like the result to return 'Date' or Cell reference where 'Date' is found, or specific text from the string?